# Relational data Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on a project that has relational data. This project is in Redux and I have a problem. I tried very hard but I can't show the "keywords" in the front. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the reducer:

```
case START_DOWNLOAD_KEYWORDS:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
                thisdomain: action.payload
            }
        case DOWNLOAD_KEYWORDS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                keywords: state.keywords.filter(keyword => keyword.project_id == state.thisdomain)
            }
```

Here is the action:

```
export function getKeywordsAction(id) {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(startDownloadKeywords(id));
        try {
            const response = await clienteAxios.get('/keywords');
            dispatch(downloadKeywordsSuccess(response.data));
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            dispatch(downloadKeywordsError());
        }
    }
};

const startDownloadKeywords = (id) => ({
    type: START_DOWNLOAD_KEYWORDS,
    payload: id
});

const downloadKeywordsSuccess = keywords => ({
    type: DOWNLOAD_KEYWORDS_SUCCESS,
    payload: keywords
});
```

And finally here is the container:

```
const { id } = props.match.params;


    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect( () => {
        // Consultar la api
        const chargeKeywords = (id) => dispatch(getKeywordsAction(id));
        chargeKeywords(id);

    }, []);

    //obtener el state
    const keywords = useSelector(state => state.domains.keywords);
```

So after this, I call {keywords} with a map but I can't see anything because keywords.length === 0.

In START_DOWNLOAD_KEYWORDS: I get:

```
{
  domains: {
    domains: [],
    error: null,
    loading: true,
    domaindelete: null,
    thisdomain: '3',
    keywords: []
  }
}
```

And in DOWNLOAD_KEYWORDS_SUCCESS this:

```
{
  domains: {
    domains: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Bla bla',
        url: 'http://blabla.com',
        country: 'España'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Hello',
        url: 'https://hellok.com',
        country: 'España'
      }
    ],
    error: null,
    loading: false,
    domaindelete: null,
    thisdomain: '3',
    keywords: []
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Maybe there is an issue with the way you reference your project_id? Shouldn't it be 

 keywords: state.keywords.filter(keyword => keyword.id == state.thisdomain)

would be keen to see what the axios get call returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem of your code is in `case DOWNLOAD_KEYWORDS_SUCCESS`

In this line `keywords: state.keywords.filter(keyword => keyword.project_id`

it should be `keywords: action.payload.filter(keyword => keyword.project_id`

Your state at this point is not changed, the `action.payload` is the updated data.

Comment: This was the problem, thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I see a mistake in the reducer, must be ===. But still with the same problem:

```
keywords: state.keywords.filter(keyword => keyword.project_id === state.thisdomain)
```